# MarkLogic: Cannot run Admin interface in browser on Windows 7

Tags: marklogic

I have a client who I am trying to help remotely, and they will not give me access to their machine, so it's a little difficult.

- He cannot run the Admin interface in his browser.
- He is on Windows 7 64-bit.
- It is a first time install for his PC.
- He downloaded the MarkLogic 7 .msi, ran it, and followed the instructions in the Installation Guide.
- When he goes to http://localhost:8001 in his browser, he gets an error that it is not found.
- Per the instructions, he right-clicked on Start MarkLogic Server in the Start programs menu and selected Run as administrator.
- But he still gets the error in the browser.
- He confirmed that no other websites are using that port on his PC.
- The Windows service stops for some reason.

Are there log files he can look at?
Does anyone have any clue how I can help him get up and running?

**EDIT 1**

```
2014-07-04 10:47:25.490 Notice: Starting MarkLogic Server 7.0-3 amd64 in C:\Program Files\MarkLogic with data in C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data
2014-07-04 10:47:58.355 Info: SSL FIPS mode has been enabled
2014-07-04 10:48:49.490 Emergency: Initialization: SVC-MEMALLOC: Memory allocation error: VirtualAlloc 134217728 bytes: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.


2014-07-04 11:07:28.981 Notice: Starting MarkLogic Server 7.0-3 amd64 in C:\Program Files\MarkLogic with data in C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data
2014-07-04 11:07:29.740 Info: SSL FIPS mode has been enabled
2014-07-04 11:07:36.885 Info: Native plugin cache manifest initialized
2014-07-04 11:07:36.909 Warning: Retrying 0 of 5 _beginthreadex: Failed to create thread: ResumeThread failed to resume: errno=0 : No error
2014-07-04 11:07:37.110 Warning: Retrying 1 of 5 _beginthreadex: Failed to create thread: ResumeThread failed to resume: errno=0 : No error
2014-07-04 11:07:37.310 Warning: Retrying 2 of 5 _beginthreadex: Failed to create thread: ResumeThread failed to resume: errno=0 : No error
2014-07-04 11:07:37.510 Warning: Retrying 3 of 5 _beginthreadex: Failed to create thread: ResumeThread failed to resume: errno=0 : No error
2014-07-04 11:07:38.299 Emergency: Initialization: SVC-THRCREAT: Thread creation error: _beginthreadex: The handle is invalid.


2014-07-04 12:09:44.938 Notice: Starting MarkLogic Server 7.0-3 amd64 in C:\Program     Files\MarkLogic with data in C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data
2014-07-04 12:09:45.823 Info: SSL FIPS mode has been enabled
2014-07-04 12:09:50.829 Emergency: Initialization: SVC-MEMALLOC: Memory allocation error: VirtualAlloc 134217728 bytes: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.


2014-07-04 12:14:05.972 Notice: Starting MarkLogic Server 7.0-3 amd64 in C:\Program Files\MarkLogic with data in C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data
2014-07-04 12:14:06.936 Info: SSL FIPS mode has been enabled
2014-07-04 12:14:20.406 Emergency: Initialization: SVC-MEMALLOC: Memory allocation error: VirtualAlloc 134217728 bytes: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.


2014-07-04 12:17:27.072 Notice: Starting MarkLogic Server 7.0-3 amd64 in C:\Program Files\MarkLogic with data in C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data
2014-07-04 12:17:28.242 Info: SSL FIPS mode has been enabled
2014-07-04 12:17:43.696 Emergency: Initialization: SVC-MEMALLOC: Memory allocation error: VirtualAlloc 67108864 bytes: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
```

Comment: Oh, brother, thanks for the downvote, man ... Seriously?  If you knew MarkLogic, you would know their development website directs its users to this site.  If you knew StackOverflow, you would know it is not limited to programming questions. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: Come on, Alexander.  It is a common software tool that has its own tag on this website.  I already asked where the log files are ... it's my first question.  I already said the error is "not found".  With all due respect, please go to a different question, because you are not helping on this one.  Thank you.

Comment: MarkLogic also has a developer mailing list, and I also submitted the question there.

Comment: One could argue that this particular question would be more appropriate on for instance serverfault.com. But apart from that I think it is hardly worth the discussion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the `MarkLogic` installer with its defaults, `MarkLogic` ends up in Program Files. Its data files, including logs, end up there on Windows as well, by default. The most interesting log file is `ErrorLog.txt`, you can find it at:

```
C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Data\Logs\ErrorLog.txt
```

**Note**: These logs are rotated daily, and preserved for 6 days. If you are looking for the one of yesterday, it will be `ErrorLog_1.txt`.

With regard to the reason why MarkLogic won't start: that is a bit difficult to tell without more information. It is likely that the **ErrorLog** will tell more.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will tell him to reboot and possibly get more memory and also increase the paging file size.

Comment: It's definitely the paging file: `The paging file is too small for this operation to complete`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the log, there is a memory issue. How much memory is onboard?
May e you need to increase the swap space. That should be at least as big as the size of the memory. So if your machine has 8gb memory. The swap space should be at least that size.
Hope this helps.
Peter